# query on lead history not working

Tags: soql, error

The above query results in an error

```
SELECT MAX(CreatedDate),OldValue,NewValue 
FROM LeadHistory 
GROUP BY OldValue,NewValue
```

The error :

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:69 field 'OldValue' can not be grouped in a
>   query call

Can someone explain this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute this code in "Developer Console"/"Debug"/"Open Execute Anonymous Window":

```
System.debug('>>> isGroupable=' + LeadHistory.OldValue.getDescribe().isGroupable());
```

you will see that `false` is returned and the documentation says:

> isGroupable() Returns true if the field can be included in the GROUP BY clause of a SOQL query, false otherwise

So this is a limitation of the platform, and you will have to query the values ungrouped and use Apex code to achieve your desired logic instead.

Comment: Thanks Kieth for your valuable information. I have one scenario where

Comment: I want to get only the latest update about owner change on particular lead record by querying leadhistory object.my query is select createdate, oldvalue, newvalue from leadhistory where leadid='0145545xyz' .This will return all the records from created date to new date.

Comment: I will get my desired result by using order by on created date with LIMIT=1 . But I want it in efficient way. Please help.

Comment: Adding something like "Field = 'Owner'" to the where and adding "order by CreatedDate desc" should do it. But if you run into problems I suggest a new question. Also please accept the above answer as what we are discussing here is beyond the scope of your question.